# What's the best Laravel Eloquent way to structure this

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

If the question is not StackOverflow-y I don't mind moderators to close it, I couldn't decide.

I have the following models: Users, Groups, Regions, Cities... There are like 4 of them. Every user can have multiple relations to each entity (administrator, manager, participant and some others)

Should I do a Relations table as follows:

```
user_id | target_id | target_type | relationship_type
      1 |         2 |       group |           manager
```

And if so - how would I use Eloquent relations - HasManyThrough somehow?

Or is the Eloquent way something else? Maybe different tables for each entity `(user_group, user_region)` ?

The goal is to have each "Groups where Peter is admin in", "Regions where Jessica is participant" queried easily via Eloquent.

Comment: You can read through [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) it would solve at least half of your problem (the target will be polymorphic). The rest can be handled using `withPivot('relationship_type')` to also include the relationship type when loading related models

Comment: I see, that looks very nice, would this be a One to Many? It seems so.

Comment: I think it would make more sense if you had a many to many polymorphic relationship between Users and Groups/Regions/Cities and have the table you shared act as the pivot.